# How to achieve a thread-safe or immutable collection in fastutils?

Tags: java, multithreading, fastutil

Fastutil seems to be the fastest option for collections in Java.

There are these javadocs:
http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/longs/Long2ObjectMaps.SynchronizedMap.html

but I have difficulty to find the usage example.

How can I have a synchronized (thread-safe?) map? An immutable map?

Comment: That class implements the ``Map`` interface. Isn't that all you need?

Comment: But this library has types of maps - eg long2object. How i should combine these with synchronized?

Answer (score 1):

Each map type has its own synchronized wrapper class (e.g. `Long2ObjectMaps.SynchronizedMap` as you linked above). To use it, instantiate a concrete map implementation, then use the corresponding `…Maps.synchronize()` method to get the synchronized version:

```
Long2ObjectMap<Foo> unsynched = new Long2ObjectOpenHashMap<>();

// this is actually a Long2ObjectMaps.SynchronizedMap
Long2ObjectMap<Foo> synched = Long2ObjectMaps.synchronize(unsynchronized);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lightweight thread-safe alternative: [FastUtil Concurrent Wrapper](https://github.com/trivago/fastutil-concurrent-wrapper) .

Compared to the default fastutil synchronization approach via `synchronized(mutex)` The Wrapper uses `striped ReadWriteLocks` (with different modes) which have better performance in some cases.